# Did Emma Watson's movie The Colony gross £47 in its UK opening weekend?

Tags: movies

According to Breitbart<sup>1</sup>, Emma Watson starred in a movie which they claim grossed approximately US$61 in the UK:

> After having spent years starring in the blockbuster Harry Potter film
>   franchise, Emma Watson’s latest film, The Colony, pulled in a paltry
>   £47 in her native United Kingdom this weekend — or about $60.75 in
>   U.S. dollars.

Source: [Emma Watson Movie Flops with $61 Opening Weekend](http://www.breitbart.com/big-hollywood/2016/07/07/emma-watsons-new-movie-made-61-opening-weekend/), 7 Jul 2016

Other news seems to corroborate this:

> Emma Watson’s first major film role since the end of the Harry Potter
>   series met with a lukewarm box office response, after taking only £47
>   in its opening weekend.

Source: [Emma Watson's new film, The Colony, takes just £47 in opening weekend](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/07/06/emma-watsons-new-film-the-colony-takes-just-47-in-opening-weeken/), 6 July 2016

While the movie did have a staggered release worldwide over the course of many months, it does appear that at least the timing matches those news stories:

> UK 1 July 2016

Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4005402/releaseinfo)

I am having a difficult time finding accurate, consistent numbers for the movie's box office releases. Several news sources make a similar assertion, but the only official numbers I can find that are not aggregated are from [IMDB, for Italy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4005402/business). All other numbers seem to indicate the total theatrical run for the UK, or the total run internationally.

Did [The Colony (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4005402/) truly gross £47 (USD$61) in its opening box office weekend in the UK? If not, how much did it gross?

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know this is the opening line of several bad jokes.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but it might be better on the movies.SE site since it might attract more expert answers and would be of higher notability.

Comment: @matt_black I figured since it is asking more about the media attention and accuracy it belonged here.

Comment: Meh. The superscript "1" renders as just 1 in text blurb, making people think the question has a typo.

Comment: Was "Noah" not a major film role? Not really part of the main claim but that caught my eye.

Comment: @Patrick87 I would classify it as a major role, but when I was reading up on the topic it seems that some journalists feel the need to omit it because it [failed to pull a profit in the US box office](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1959490/business). I get a feeling that the media doesn't count the international box office for whether a US film flops or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the British Film Institute documented in their July 1-3 2016 report.

### [UK weekend box office report: 1-3 July 2016](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.bfi.org.uk/sites/bfi.org.uk/files/downloads/bfi-weekend-box-office-report-1-3-july-2016.xls):

> Rank: 84
>
> Film: The Colony
>
> Country of Origin: Ger/Fra/Lux
>
> Weekend Gross: £47
>
> Distributor: Signature Entertainment
>
> % change on last week: -
>
> Weeks on release: 1
>
> Number of cinemas: 3
>
> Site average: £16
>
> Total Gross to date: £47

A meager £47 isn't quite as sensation as it may appear though when you see their stats are being pulled from only 3 theaters.

I don't know if it was released in more than just the 3 theaters that reported these stats, but that's enough ticket sales for a couple of people in each theater.

There were also many bigger films released that weekend.